# jPlayer play next file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I'm trying to use jPlayer for playing background music on service.

Here is my code:

```
    if (command.indexOf('playmusic') != -1) {
        var player = document.getElementById('jpId');
        $(player).jPlayer(
            {
                ready: function () {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        mp3: "../../audio/1.mp3"
                    }).jPlayer("play");
                }, supplied: "mp3"
            }
        );
    }
    if (command.indexOf('playnext') != -1) {
        var player = document.getElementById('jpId');
        $(player).setFile("../../audio/2.mp3");
        $(player).play();
    }
```

but playnext part of code not working:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setFile'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do

```
$('#jpId').jPlayer('setMedia', {
  mp3: '../../audio/2.mp3',
}).jPlayer('play');
```

Instead of

```
var player = document.getElementById('jpId');
$(player).setFile("../../audio/2.mp3");
$(player).play();
```